# "Comments on deleted questions cannot be upvoted" when the question is on hold

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, up-votes, on-hold

I received the red popup message, "Comments on deleted questions cannot be upvoted", when the question was *on hold*, **not** deleted!

It appears that the message just hasn't been adjusted since the on-hold update... **But** I should be able to upvote comments since I can still *add* a new comment to questions that are on hold.

This is both a bug (the popup is wrong!) and a feature request (let me upvote!).

[image: Popup when upvoting a comment on a question that is on hold]

Comment: I can up-vote comments of on-hold questions. Are sure the question wasn't deleted after you accessed it but before you clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778002/can-somebody-please-help-me-with-the-code-im-really-a-beginner-in-this-topic) was in fact deleted almost immediately after it was closed. Likely it was deleted at the time you tried to upvote the comment, the popup error message was correct, and there isn't actually an issue here.

Comment: :) Things happen tooo fast! Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: That question is only a few hours old... I thought we changed it so that users couldn't vote to delete a question immediately after downvoting/closing?

Comment: @CodyGray: Users can't immediately delete a question unless it has a score lower than -2.